# how to create FBML in facebook application ?

Tags: fbml

Canvas is the application used to create a FBML / iframe had the option. New applications do not have this option. How do FBML

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Facebook has phased out the FBML. It will be officially deprecated as of June 6, 2012. You can use XFBML in some settings such as Social Plugins and alongside the JS SDK.